# MySQL Workbench: 'Use the old authentication protocol.' option causes error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try to connect to an old MySQL database using MySQL Workbench using the `Use the old authentication protocol` option under the Advanced tab, MySQL Workbench returns this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_tables_name' at line 1

- Workbench v6.1.7
- MySQL server v3.23.41 on RedHat
- Database and Tables
  are lowercase and uppercase (camelCase).

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had to look this up, as I do not have any 3.x any more:

```
The GLOBAL and SESSION modifiers are new in MySQL 4.0.3.
```

I also got this:

```
Oracle MySQL Workbench does not support MySQL Server versions 4.x.
```

Your best option is stick to the mysql command line client (or update MySQL Server, as 3.23.41 was released on 11 August 2001).